# open a file whose name and directory are determined by the content selected in combobox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, combobox

I have a combobox (*combobox1*) with a list of names for example: CHARLY SUSAN BOB.

What I'm trying to achieve is to read the contents of a corresponding file in another combobox (*combobox2*) so

- CHARLY would open CHARLY.txt and populate combobox2 with that files
  contents
- SUSAN would open SUSAN.txt and populate combobox2 with that
  files contents
- BOB would open BOB.txt and populate combobox2 with
  that files contents

The list of names its self is read from a text file this is because I would in future like to add more names.

These are read into (*Combobox1*) by the following code:

```
'Compiles list for plotter/ printer items...
ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\PEOPLE\NAMES.txt"))
```

I’m thinking to keep the concept open to an ever expanding list to set a variable/ string to the target name then add a prefix to it example being: BOBfile.txt with a suffix also added which would point to the target files directory thus then being `C:\PEOPLE\BOBSfile.txt`

This set in a variable would then open the concerning folder as follows:

```
ComboBox2.Items.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines( BOBSVARIABLE ))
```

Dose anybody know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
                                        Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
  If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
    ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
  Else
    Dim peoplePath As String = "C:\PEOPLE"
    Dim personFile As String = Path.Combine(peoplePath, _
                                            ComboBox1.SelectedItem & "file.txt")
    If File.Exists(personFile) Then
      ComboBox2.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(personFile))
    Else
      ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Do consider a database instead.  Also, your current system wouldn't handle duplicate names very well.